# Взаимодействие модулей в Java

Tags: java, модули, java-9

В процессе изучения модулей задался вопросом что может использовать модуль ?
Т.е. у меня есть такая структура
`/mymodapp/appsrc/appfuncs/appfuncs/simplefuncs/SimpleMathFuncs.java`

```
package appfuncs.simplefuncs;

public class SimpleMathFuncs {

// выяснить является ли множитель a множителем b

public static boolean isFactor(int a, int b) {
    if((b%a) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

// возвратить наименьший общий для a и b
// положительный множитель 

public static int lcf(int  a, int b) {
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);

    int min = a < b ? a : b;

    for(int i = 2; i <= min/2; i++) {
        if(isFactor(i, a) && isFactor(i, b))
            return i;
    }
    return 1;
}

    // возвратить наибольший общий для a и b
    // положитльный множитель

public static int gcf(int a, int b){

    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);

    int  min = a < b ? a  : b;

    for(int i = min/2; i>= 2; i--) {
        if(isFactor(i, a) && isFactor(i, b))
            return i;
        }
    return 1;
    }
}
```

`/mymodapp/appsrc/appfuncs/module-info.java`

```
    //Определение модуля математических функций 
module appfuncs {
    // экспортировать пакет appfuncs.simplefuncs
    exports appfuncs.simplefuncs;
}
```

а так же

```
appsrc/appstart/appstart/mymodappdemo/MyModAppDemo.java
```

```
package appstart.mymodappdemo;
import appfuncs.simplefuncs.SimpleMathFuncs;
public class MyModAppDemo {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        if(SimpleMathFuncs.isFactor(2, 10))
            System.out.println ("2 - множитель 10");

        System.out.println("Haимeньший общий множитель "
                 + "35 и 105 - "
                 + SimpleMathFuncs.lcf (35, 105 ));

        System.out.println("Haибoльший общий множитель "
                 + "35 и 105 - "
                 + SimpleMathFuncs.gcf(35, 105));
    }
}
```

Класс который использует этот модуль, его тоже стоит поместить в модуль ?
и есть ли возможность изменить структуру проекта что бы всё работало без оборачивания в модуль ?

Comment: Если класс использует модуль, то да(`Инкапсуляция`). Если вы не хотите создавать модуль, то просто не создавайте его, уберите `module-info.java`